# Argument value in function changes to empty string after Try Catch part of function

Tags: php, mysql

I created a function (isPasswordCorrect) to check user password against hashed password in database. For some reason, the value of $password is lost after the MySQL query portion of the function.

User email and password are passed from the form to the function. These values exist after the function is called, as demonstrated in the code below.

I cannot understand how or why the $password value changes to an empty string after the Try Catch. I can get it to work by saving the $password value into a SESSION variable, but this seems incorrect and undesirable.

The code works with $_SESSION['password'], but this doesn't explain what happened to the $password value.

Any assistance is appreciated.

```
<?php

// Boolean function to check user password against stored password
function isPasswordCorrect($email, $password){

    // Check if values being passed into function  - OK
    echo 'email: ' . $email . '<br>';
    echo 'password: ' . $password;

    // Solution to make this work, but not desirable
    $_SESSION['password'] = $password;

    // Connect to database
    include 'admin/includes/dbconnect-local.php';

    // Access table to retrieve hashed password
    try 
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT password FROM user
            WHERE email = :email';
        $s = $db->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(':email', $email);
        $s->execute();
    } 
    catch(PDOException $e) 
    {
        $error = 'Error fetching password.' . $e->getMessage();
        include 'admin/content_editors/error.html.php';
        exit();
    }

    // Assign single row result to $result
    $result = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // Verify hashed password value was retrieved and being passed through function - OK
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";

    /***********************************************************************************/
    // Verify $password value. DISCOVER THAT $password value is now EMPTY STRING! - NOT OK 
    echo 'password: ' . $password . '<br>';

    // Verify SESSION password value - OK
    echo 'SESSION password: ' . $_SESSION['password'];

    // Check for match using password_verify() - WORKS ONLY USING $_SESSION['password'] - NOT REALLY OK
    if(password_verify($_SESSION['password'], $result['password']))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }   
}

// Call function after post of submitted data
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'submit')
{
    if(isPasswordCorrect($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']))
    {
        echo '<p style="color:#0000ff;">Match found!</p>';
        // Check values used in function - OK
        echo '<p>' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>';
        echo '<p>' . $_POST['password'] . '</p>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<p style="color:#ff0000;">Sorry, match not found.</p>';
        // Check values used in function - OK 
        echo '<p>' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>';
        echo '<p>' . $_POST['password'] . '</p>';
    }
}

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Password Verify</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder=" Email">
            <input type="text" name="password" placeholder=" Password">
            <button type="submit" name="action" value="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you store password as plain text?

Comment: Is there a `$password` variable in your `'admin/includes/dbconnect-local.php'` file?

Comment: @lad2025 the password entered by the user is 123456, and in the database is $hashed_password = password_hash('123456', PASSWORD_DEFAULT)

Comment: @RocketHazmat. Sorry, YES. $password is in fact in the included file!

Comment: @RocketHazmat  Brilliant!  You are precisely correct. I changed $password to $user_password and it works. Thanks for taking your time to take a look at this, and for solving this mystery. Great work!  Thank you!

Comment: @JimB814: You're welcome :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `include` statement basically tells PHP to copy and paste the contents of the included file into your script at that spot, then continue executing.

If there is a `$password` variable inside your `'admin/includes/dbconnect-local.php'` file, it would *overwrite* the `$password` variable from your function.